# How to set the values to: KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<String,String>,int>

Tags: c#, keyvaluepair

C#
I am using a KeyValuePair as a key in my main KeyValuePair.
Here is my problem:

If I have "KeyValuePair", the declaration would be as following:

```
KeyValuePair<String,String> varName = new KeyValuePair<String,String>("String 1","String 2");
```

How do I declare it if i have the following:

```
KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<String,String>,int>
```

I got so lost in the syntax here. Please help me out!

Thank you!

Comment: Dude which language.. what code you have tried.. if you can tell would be better i think...

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear enough. My bad, it is C#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much have it, but it's easiest to split it into two initialisations.

Firstly, initialise the `KeyValuePair<string, string>` and then use that along with an `int` to initalise the `KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>`:

```
var pair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>("string 1", "string 2");
var varName = new KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>(pair, 10);
```

You can simplify this considerably if you write a helper method like so:

```
public static KeyValuePair<T1, T2> MakeKeyValuePair<T1, T2>(T1 key, T2 value)
{
    return new KeyValuePair<T1, T2>(key, value);
}
```

Using that, you can do the following instead:

```
var pair    = MakeKeyValuePair("string 1", "string 2");
var varName = MakeKeyValuePair(pair, 10);
```

This is much easier to follow, and you don't need to explicitly specify the types.

Or if you prefer (I personally don't prefer this):

```
var varName = MakeKeyValuePair(MakeKeyValuePair("string 1", "string 2"), 10);
```

But if you really want to do it the hard way:

```
var varName = new KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>(
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("string 1", "string 2"), 
    10);
```

Comment: Yeah I though of that but why easy if I can do it the hard way. :D Could you help out on the hard one, how to mix these two lines of code into one?

Comment: And without any additional methods: `new KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<String,String>,int>(new KeyValuePair<String,String>("String 1","String 2"), 42)`.

Comment: @КристиянКостадинов Sure, see my latest edit. :)   Хорошего дня!

Comment: Thank you! you are the best! :P